# How to check if a list of strings are present in two separate files

Tags: python, text, sed, awk, compare

I have two files, "File A" is a list of IP Addresses with corresponding MAC addresses on the same line. "File B" is a list of only MAC addresses. I need to compare the two files and list the lines from File A that do not have MAC addresses found in File B.

FILE A:

```
172.0.0.1 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:01
172.0.0.2 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:02
172.0.0.3 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:03
```

FILE B:

```
AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:01
AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:02
```

So the output should be:

```
172.0.0.3 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:03
```

I am looking for solutions in sed, awk, grep, python or really anything that give me the file I want.

Comment: Do your files really have a dollar sign at the start of each line? It's easier if they don't.

Comment: They do not have a dollar sign. I have edited the question to reflect this. Thanks.

Comment: Great. Then see the `fgrep` answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Does your input really have a dollar sign at the start of every line, or is that a formatting quirk of your question? If you can get rid of the dollar signs, then you can use this:

```
fgrep -v -f fileb filea
```

Comment: This is great.  By far the best answer here (in my opinion).

Comment: This works. I had to change one of the input files to make the case consistent. I used this:
`tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < macs > macslower`

Comment: You could also just add `-i` to `fgrep` for a case-insensitive match.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
with open('fileb') as fileb, open('filea') as filea:
    macs = set(map(str.strip, fileb))
    for line in filea:
        ip_mac = line.split()
        if len(ip_mac) == 2 and ip_mac[1] not in macs:
           print(" ".join(ip_mac))
```

Comment: `line.split()` is slightly more general than `line.split(' ')` (this will choke if the IP and MAC are separated by 2 spaces for example).  Also, this assumes there is no extra whitespace on lines in fileb.

Comment: @mgilson: `.split()` strips newlines. I agree this version is "whitespace fragile".

Comment: @mgilson: I've made it less sensitive to varying whitespace

Comment: Now I'm happy with this (+1)  :)

Comment: I've removed '$' handling (question is updated) and made more robust against invalid input

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('filea','r') as fa:    
    with open('fileb','r') as f:
        MACS=set(line.strip() for line in f)

    for line in fa:
        IP,MAC=line.split()
        if MAC not in MACS:
            print (line.strip())
```

Comment: You could use a single `with`-statement to avoid creating the `set()` if filea is unreadable. There should be no `$` in the output.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian : I don't like having multiple things in the same `with` statement.  To me it's cluttered and hard to read.  But you're right.  If I nest my `with` statements, then I can avoid the scenario you described.  Updated.  Also stripped off the $ in the output.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open(FILEB) as file1,open(FILEA) as file2:
file1={mac.strip() for mac in file1}
file2={line.split()[1]:line.split()[0] for line in file2}
    for x in file2:
        if x not in file1:
            print("{0} {1}".format(file2[x],x))
```

**output:**

```
172.0.0.2 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:05
172.0.0.4 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:06
172.0.0.6 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:03
172.0.0.66 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:0E
```

Comment: `rstrip().split()` is completely equivalent to `strip()`.

Comment: mgilson meant `.split()` ignores trailing whitespace

Comment: `if x not in file1` is O(n) in your case. Use `set()` instead of list. Dictionary is unnecessary in this case. The code is unreadable

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary -- J.F.Sebastian is right.  what I meant to say was `rstrip().split()` is equivalent to `split()`.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

One way using `awk`. It saves MACs from `fileB` in an array and for each second field of `fileA` check it in the array and only print when not found.

```
awk '
    FNR == NR {
        data[ $0 ] = 1;
        next;
    }
    NFR < NR && !($2 in data)
' fileB fileA
```

Output:

```
172.0.0.3 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:03
```

Comment: This seems to return the entire contents of fileA.

Comment: +1, but instead of substr, you should be using `mac = $0` or just `data[ $0 ] = 1`  And the 2nd block can be simplified to `NFR < NR && !($2 in data)`

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Thank you. I edited the answer with your suggestions. *Cpashia* edited the question but just before IPs had a sigil as first character, and I used the `substr` function to remove it. And so I realized the previous comment stating that the program did not work. Fixed already.

Answer (score 1):

Python:

```
macs = set(line.strip() for line in open('fileb'))
with open('filea') as ips:
    for line in ips:
        ip,mac = line.split()
        if mac not in macs:
            print line
```

**EDIT**: OK so everyone posted the same python answer.  I reach for python first too but
**gawk** at this:

```
awk 'NR == FNR {fileb[$1];next} !($2 in fileb)' fileb filea
```

**EDIT2**: OP removed the leading $ from the lines so python and awk change and fgrep comes out to play.

```
fgrep -v -f fileb filea
```

Comment: The awk solution seems to return the entire contents of fileA. While the python solution gripes at me with a syntax error. 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pycompare.py", line 4, in <module>
    ip,mac = line.split()
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack'

Comment: @cpashia  looks ok to be but I get your result if a and b are reversed.  in awk fileb comes first (mac addresses).  I used your original file names.

Answer (score 0):

Python is easiest. Read File B into a dictionary, then go through File A and look for a match in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I could whip up a Java example that you could translate to whatever language you want

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class Macs {
    public static void main(String...args)throws Exception {
        Set<String> macs = loadLines("macs.txt");
        Set<String> ips = loadLines("ips.txt");

        for(String raw : ips) {
            String[] tokens = raw.split("\\s"); // by space
            String ip = tokens[0];
            String mac = tokens[1];
            if(!macs.contains(mac))
                System.out.println(raw);
        } 
    }

    static Set<String> loadLines(String filename) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        Set<String> lines = new HashSet<String>();
        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
            // substring(1) removes leading $
            lines.add(sc.nextLine().substring(1).toLowerCase());
        }
        return lines;
    }
}
```

Redirecting this output to a file will give you your result.

With the following input file of

macs.txt

```
$AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:01
$AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:02
$AA:BB:CF:DD:EE:09
$AA:EE:CF:DD:EE:09
```

ips.txt

```
$172.0.0.1 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:01
$172.0.0.2 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:02
$172.0.0.2 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:05
$172.0.0.66 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:0E
$172.0.0.4 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:06
$172.0.0.5 AA:BB:CF:DD:EE:09
$172.0.0.6 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:03
```

Result:

```
c:\files\j>java Macs
172.0.0.6 aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:03
172.0.0.66 aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:0e
172.0.0.2 aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:05
172.0.0.4 aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:06
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GUN sed);

```
sed 's|.*|/&/Id|' fileb | sed -f - filea
```